# Git checkout --ours path/to/file.txt returns "updated 0 paths from the index"

Tags: git, github, binaryfiles, merge-conflict-resolution

When trying to fix merge issues of binary files I use the git checkout --ours path/to/file.txt but it keeps returning Updated 0 paths from Index. Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: That just means that the current version of the file matches the `--ours` version of the file. It's not an *error*, it's just information.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, that should means nothing was updated because it was not needed to be updated.

Since Git 2.23 (Q3 2019), the right command would be

```
git restore --ours -- path/to/file.txt
```

If you are still using git checkout, use Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), because "[`git checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/acdb1e1053c5bc0832866780bb517f7465aea7a2/Documentation/git-checkout.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout))</sup> miscounted the paths it updated, which has been corrected.

See [commit 611c778](https://github.com/git/git/commit/611c7785e8e22637e183333c54ed266e6e83e163), [commit 11d14de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11d14dee43794581ca3a7a93f9a081de711845d4), [commit ed602c3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed602c3f448c2681b16245d4a489342a2db89855) (14 Jul 2022) by [Matheus Tavares (`matheustavares`)](https://github.com/matheustavares).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit acdb1e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/acdb1e1053c5bc0832866780bb517f7465aea7a2), 01 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/611c7785e8e22637e183333c54ed266e6e83e163): fix two bugs on the final count of updated entries
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Matheus Tavares</sup>

> At the end of [`git checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/611c7785e8e22637e183333c54ed266e6e83e163/Documentation/git-checkout.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout))</sup> `<pathspec>`, we get a message informing how many entries were updated in the working tree.
> However, this number can be inaccurate for two reasons:
>
> 1. Delayed entries currently get counted twice.
> 2. Failed entries are included in the count.
>
> The first problem happens because the counter is first incremented before inserting the entry in the delayed checkout queue, and once again when `finish_delayed_checkout()` calls `checkout_entry()`.
>
> And the second happens because the counter is incremented too early in `checkout_entry()`, before the entry was in fact checked out.
>
> Fix that by moving the count increment further down in the call stack and removing the duplicate increment on delayed entries.
>
> Note that we have to keep a per-entry reference for the counter (both on parallel checkout and delayed checkout) because not all entries are always accumulated at the same counter.
>
> See `checkout_worktree()`, at [`builtin/checkout.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/611c7785e8e22637e183333c54ed266e6e83e163/builtin/checkout.c) for an example.